# Group two dimensional list records Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, group-by

Using Python 3 I have a list that looks like this:

list = [["A",24],["B",22],["F",2],["A",4],["F",16],["A",6]]

So I just want to group the above results as below:

[["A",34],["B",22],["F",18]]

what is the best way to get it.